# Is there a way to select a child element of table first table with same class name, then select the 1st td element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, children

I am trying to apply a style to table data, but cannot get correct  element since they Don't have classes or IDs. The tables have the same class name, and I have been able to isolate the correct table by using table:nth-of-type(2). I just can't figure out how to string together the selectors correctly to get the correct  element.

The most recent thing I have tried is

div#esri_dijit_Legend_0_BuckQuery table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td:first-child

Below is a diagram of the html

```
<table class="className">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>  Need to apply style to this element only
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="className">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>  Don't want this element
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



No errors, just nothing happens.The problem I am having is stringing together to two selectors correctly. I know there is a correct syntax for doing this.

Thanks
```

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Your style doesn't apply to any of them? Looks like it should? Are there other tables with different class names? Why are you using `table:nth-of-type(2)` if you want the first one? See https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/4Lbg9831/ This should be enough `table:nth-of-type(1)  td:first-child `

Comment: Need more clarification on what element you need to target. Just the first `<td>` or all of them?

Comment: Indeed, that looks like it should work, assuming the first table.className is in fact the second table and the first one is not shown.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
   .className:first-of-type  tr:first-child td:first-child
   {
     background:red;
   }
</style>

<table class="className">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>  Need to apply style to this element only
            <td>
            <td> 
              There is no style on this element
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="className">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>  Don't want this element
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```